Liquidity of SPX options with tenors over 2 years
I see that Bloomberg provides SPX index volatility surface values for option tenors up to and including 5 years. I used option tenors of up to 2 years in the past (over five years ago) when I worked with equity options models. In the opinion of practitioners, is there sufficient liquidity for tenors over 2 years to use these for model calibration? For example, on 9/17/24, the bid/ask for the ATM at 5 years is 69 bps, compared with the 30 bps bid/ask for the 2-year ATM, and 8 bps for the 1-year ATM.

The values are greyed out, meaning they are extrapolated because there isn't enough liquidity to compute them.

7 and 10-year expiry are greyed out, but 3, 4, and 5-year are active.
